# Parsing python dicts with JACKSON

Tags: java, python, json, dictionary, jackson

I would like to parse python dicts. There are 2 differences between json and python dicts:

- python dicts allow simple quotte (easy to do with jackson using jsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES).
- for booleans, python dicts have "True" and "False" instead of "true" and "false".

Do you know if how to be case insensitive on "True" and "False" with jackson ?

Thanks a lot for your help, it is blocking for me.

Best regards,

Jérôme Odier

My code:

```
private static final ObjectMapper m_objectMapper = new ObjectMapper(
    new JsonFactory().enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a github issue for this problem in Jackson project
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/1852

There is also a Pull Request for the issue which you can make use of
https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/pull/2132